# How do I find the maximum value of a field in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, max

I have a table called courses. The fields are:

```
id, category, sortorder, fullname, etc.....
```

What I am trying to do is given the category I want to find the maximum sortorder number in that category and then increment that number and use this new number for my new row.

For example: I have `category = 30` and it will return the numbers 1 to 10. I want to retrieve 10 because it is the highest number but I don't know what the highest number will actually be in each query. After I get the value 10 I will add 1 to it and then use it for my new course.

How should I do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `MAX()` function of MySQL.

So do something like:

```
SELECT MAX(sortorder) as maximum FROM courses WHERE category = 10
```

Comment: This works but I don't understand because I thought you can't use aggregate functions with WHERE clauses

Comment: you can't use them in the WHERE clauses. You'll have to use them in the HAVING. Doing a SELECT with a `MAX()` will work perfectly with a WHERE clause like the one I used in my answer. If you want to use MAX() in the WHERE, then use something like `HAVING MAX(sortorder) = 10`

Comment: Ah, I see. You can't use them INSIDE the where clause! Thanks for clearing that up. It's been since first year of university since I used MySQL !!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [max function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) in MYSQL.

Not sure what your column is called, but something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(`sortorder`) AS `max` FROM `table`
```

Comment: But that will get ALL the sortorders. I just want the ones in a given category.

Comment: Well, add a `WHERE` clause on your select statement then.

Comment: I thought you can't use aggregate functions with the where clause :S

Comment: You wouldn't use `MAX` within your `WHERE` clause. If you're looking to use this value in another query, then you'd have to do a 2nd query after this.

Comment: @Nick no need to fire another query for that.Check my answer to that.

Comment: @heyanshukla Yeah, never used `HAVING` before, looking into it just now! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Might this help

```
    SELECT MAX(sortorder)
    FROM table_name
    WHERE category = 10
```

Comment: This is giving me the lowest number for some reason :/